# Unhiding a row using a macro based on cell value (for 10000 rows)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am very new to macro. However, I found a macro on this website to hide rows with the value of False. I edited the macro to also make it unhide the row again, and it worked fine.
The problem is that I want it to work for many rows, so I make it from A1 to A10000. When I hide it works fine, but when I unhide it the Excel software will stop working (I use mac). So what should i do?

```
Sub HiddeA()
Dim A As Range
Set A = Range("A1:A10000")
A.EntireRow.Hidden = False
For i = 1 To 10000
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Cells(i, 1).Value = False Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
End Sub


Sub ShowA()
Dim A As Range
Set A = Range("A1:A10000")
A.EntireRow.Hidden = True
For i = 1 To 10000
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value = False Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You should be using `for i = 10000 to 1 step -1)` just for good reference if you want to do any deletion.

Answer (score 1):

`Sub ShowA()`should be like this:

```
Sub ShowA()
For i = 1 To 10000
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And Cells(i, 1).Value = False Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

You don't need to issue the line `A.EntireRow.Hidden = True` because it is hiding every row.

In adittion you forgot the *doublequoutes* and the `and`on the line

`If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value = False Then`

Comment: Why is there any need to check if it's empty? If it's `FALSE` it's not empty, right?

Comment: One more thing, I am trying to make for column B as well, I changed all A's to B, but it didn't work. Can you please give the right code.

Comment: More clarification: I want when there is the value FALSE on a cell on column B the macro will hide the row

Comment: To verify the False on column B change `Cells(i, 1)` to `Cells(i, 2)`